# i18next 'resGetPath' not implementing in plugin initialization

Tags: javascript, json, path, internationalization, i18next

I would like to store translation.json files with this project, and have them accessed by in18next. Unfortunately I can't seem to implement the `resGetPath` attribute correctly. When I initialize the plugin with the `resources` object, it works fine. I'm guessing there is something wrong with the path or the structure of the json file, but I can't seem to find a similar issue on SO or any of the forums for i18next (most people have larger projects that just pull from a server). I would like to simply reference the local translation file based on whatever locale is chosen by the user. Thanks for your time =).

Here is the code for translation.js which loads fine into index.html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  i18next.init({
    lng: 'en', 
    // resources: { 
    //   en: {
    //     translation: {
    //       nav: {
    //         newInvoice: 'Hakuna Matata'
    //       }
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    resGetPath:'../locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
  }, function (err, t) {
      jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $, {
        tName: 't', // --> appends $.t = i18next.t
        i18nName: 'i18n', // --> appends $.i18n = i18next
        handleName: 'localize', // --> appends $(selector).localize(opts);
        selectorAttr: 'data-i18n', // selector for translating elements
        targetAttr: 'i18n-target', // data-() attribute to grab target element to translate (if diffrent then itself)
        optionsAttr: 'i18n-options', // data-() attribute that contains options, will load/set if useOptionsAttr = true
        useOptionsAttr: false, // see optionsAttr
        parseDefaultValueFromContent: true
      });

      $('#tempTarget').localize();
    })
});
```

here is the locales/en/translations.js:

```
{
  "nav": {
    "newInvoice": "somethaaaang"
  }
}
```

here is my directory:

```
index.html
locales
   en
      translation.json
```

this is the line in the html that is correctly targeted with the `resources` object but not with the `reGetPath` attribute:

```
<a href="/new-invoice/" data-i18n='nav.newInvoice' id='tempTarget' class="panel-close">New Invoice</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resGetPath` is from the old 1.x.x days...nowadays have a look at the plugins: https://www.i18next.com/overview/plugins-and-utils#backends

in your case https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend ---> i18next.use(XHR)

the option your searching is `backend.loadPath`